# How to speed up my bilinear interpolation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, image-processing

I have spent countless hours trying to speed up my bilinear interpolation up, with no avail. I even tried a SSE version (a double version and a float version), but that was even slower than this version.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
template <typename T>
__forceinline void interp2_mx(const T& x, const T& y,
                              const T* z,
                              const int32_t& n,
                              const int32_t& mm2,
                              const int32_t& nm2,
                              T& val,
                              const T& extrapval = T(0))
{
    int64_t xp = (int64_t)(x) - 1;      // adjust for MATLAB indexing
    int64_t yp = (int64_t)(y) - 1;
    if (xp < 0 || xp > nm2 || yp < 0 || yp > mm2)
    {
        val = extrapval;
    }
    else
    {
        const T* line = z + yp * n + xp;
        T xf = x - (int64_t)(x);        
        T yf = y - (int64_t)(y);
        T x1mf = (T)1 - xf;
        T y1mf = (T)1 - yf;

        T v00 = x1mf * y1mf * (*(line));
        T v01 = xf * y1mf * (*(line + 1));     
        T v10 = x1mf * yf * (*(line + n));     
        T v11 = xf * yf * (*(line + n + 1));   
        val = v00 + v01 + v10 + v11;
    }
} 

template <typename T>
void interp2(const T* z,
             const int32_t& mz, const int32_t& nz,
             const T* xi, const T* yi,
             const int32_t& mi, const int32_t& ni,
             T* zi,
             const T& extrapval = T(0))
{
    const int32_t nzm2 = nz - 2;
    const int32_t mzm2 = mz - 2;    
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int m = 0; m < mi; ++m)
    {        
        T* line_zi = zi + m * ni;    
        const T* x = xi + m * ni;
        const T* y = yi + m * ni;
        for (int n = 0; n < ni; ++n, ++x, ++y, ++line_zi)
        {
            interp2_mx((*x), (*y), z, nz, mzm2, nzm2, (*line_zi));            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have reason to pass T by `const` reference instead of value (as it seems that it is only float/double). Passing by value may remove some aliases which forbid some optimizations.

Comment: I assumed passing by reference would be faster?

Comment: not for built-in types.

Comment: Well, considering that it's `__forceinline` and presumably actually inlined, this wouldn't matter. SSA optimization tracks the actual values. You may still have aliasing problems, but those would be due to the context in which this function is inlined.

Comment: Removing the MATLAB tag as your post has nothing to do with MATLAB.  Also, you should probably put this on Code Review instead.  This kind of question is off-topic for StackOverflow: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Okay thanks I will. I actually coded this up as a mex function because the MATLAB interp2 is much too slow (at least for the MATLAB version I'm using).

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation of `xf` does a float-to-int64_t-to-float conversion. I assume you know the value is in range, otherwise this would be Undefined Behavior (and mathematically pointless). `std::modf()` may be the better function as it directly calculates the desired value.

I also think that adjacent pixels have rather related xf & x1mf values, yet you recalculate them. I'm not sure about this as your coordinates seem to be stored indirectly (`(*x), (*y)`). It may very well be more efficient to calculate those on the fly. Since these pointers may alias the output, they can't be prefetched and the reads will be blocking the memory bus.